# how to make setup file containing a delphi exe and some other files

Tags: delphi, installation, inno-setup

I have written a utility in delphi 5 professional which requires the some files while executing. I want to make a setup file which installs my utility program along with the other required files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Installshield the only way to go for Delphi Installations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561062/is-installshield-the-only-way-to-go-for-delphi-installations)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use InnoSetup to create professional installers here is the download link ... http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: is there any tool which comes with delphi?

Comment: @naren: Actually, Borland used to ship "InstallShield Express" with Delphi, but I think only in the pro versions. You may want to take a look at your Delphi installation CD to find out whether ISExpress is shipped with your version.

Comment: +1 for innoSetup. Simple and fun.  InstallShield express is not nearly as easy to use.

Comment: InstallShield Express was very limited - but it was far easier to use than InnoSetup. InnoSetup is very powerful, but requires a little time to learn to use it. Anyway, the IS Express that came with D5 is very outdated today, while InnoSetup supports the latest Windows OSes.

Comment: I know - but naren asked for tools that came with Delphi. And ISE was the only thing that ever came with Delphi, so I told him for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Update: At this moment there is an Embarcadero RAD Studio expert which integrates Inno Setup directly in this IDE called RAD & Installer: http://rad-installer.com/ (see my answer below)

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with InnoSetup any time if using Microsoft Windows Installer is not a requirement. If you would like to use MSI, then I'd recomment diving into [Windows Installer XML](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is relatively easy to use for simple setups.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 5 came with InstallShield Express that is useful for simple setups (and IIRC could also install the BDE...) and is simple to use - if you have a "legal" copy you should find it easily on the installation CD (it should also be offered by the installation app autoruns launches).