# Self-installer for Delphi win32 application

Tags: delphi, installation, setup-deployment, win32-process, oneclick

Are there any components or 3rd party software to create the self-installer Delphi application?

I want to make some kind of one-click installer which will copy the main exe file and few other files to AppData folder and create the shortcuts. It should contain only one installation screen with few settings.

I just can't find any installation builder which will create such one-click installer.

Guess I have to store all my additional files (including uninstaller) as the resources inside of the single exe, and then unpack them into the destination folder. Maybe you know some more effective method?

Comment: Did you look at Inno or similar? Also what do you mean by appdata?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think he means "AppData" folder

Comment: @dorin but which one? Presumably the one under the user profile rather than commonappdata.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I mean AppData under the user profile.

Comment: @David most likely, tho', I don't really see the rational behind it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make setup file containing a delphi exe and some other files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706691/how-to-make-setup-file-containing-a-delphi-exe-and-some-other-files)

Comment: On other people's system, be polite. Use a sound, tested installer/uninstaller engine which will install your software properly and also remove it properly if the user decides so. A good user experience starts and ends with the installer/uninstaller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). This can be configured/scripted to do automatic installations and does not cost anything.

Comment: InnoSetup allow to make one custom setup screen with my options?

Comment: InnoSetup uses pascal script(if I remember correctly) which will allow you to create custom screens, add custom components, pretty much everything you need.

Comment: +1 For mentioning InnoSetup. It's opensource and written in Delphi moreover.

Comment: I agree with you all.  Been using InnoSetup for deliverables for years now.  No problems, just works. Does all the strange stuff like run database installers, register DLLs. Excellent.

Comment: For your purposes a little bit of installation scripting should be enough to get going.

Comment: I just used InnoSetup for the first time last week. It has a wizard to get you started, and I was setup in less than an hour with a basic self-contained EXE without any scripting.

Answer (score 4):

Use NSIS installer (Nullsoft (winamp) installer.
It is very simple and configureable.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page